# Clip raster to new column in feature?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, clip, fields-attributes

I'm trying to clip a raster using a feature set. I'd like to then have a new value added to a column in attribute table of the feature set based on the majority of the pixels in the raster.

In this illustration, raster values could be corn (y), soy (g), no data (trans). I'd like to clip with the feature and then have the "crop" column in the clip feature attribute table updated to be "soy" if it's the majority value.

QGIS solutions? ArcGIS?

[image: Goal]

Comment: Have you tried Zonal Statistics plugin in QGIS?

Comment: @Alrik Suvari Do you work with python? And this would be a single task or has to be automated?

Comment: Do you have the Spatial Analyst Extension with ArcGIS ?

Comment: Which of QGIS or ArcGIS for Desktop are you actually using and/or would prefer to be using to do this? I think you should [edit] your question to focus it on that product.